# Не выводятся данные в datagridview c#, из ms sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid, forms

не выводятся данные из таблицы в ms sql, в datagridview. Уже много часов бьюсь, но не понимаю свою ошибку. Банально показываются все столбцы, но не данные в них. В предварительном просмотре datagrid данные отображаются. Очень прошу вас помочь, хотя бы подсказать в чем может быть ошибка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если я добавляю datagrid на форму, и выбираю как источник данных другую таблицу, то все прекрасно работает.